# Unity 2D Jump & Run: Implementing Enemy Collisions for Game Over Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

I want to build a 2D jump and run game in Unity using C#. Currently, I am working on the enemies' functionality. My goal is to implement a game over scene that triggers when the player collides with an enemy. However, I'm facing difficulties in setting up the collision detection system, particularly in creating the trigger.

[Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aeaQ.png)
[enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Fle.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemytrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void onTriggerEnter2d(Collider2D collision)
    {    
        Debug.Log("Trigger Enter");
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7TLw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between Trigger and Collision.

- Trigger will detect collision but will not collide, transpassing the objecs (going through them).
- Collision will detect and collide, like real physics behaviour.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{    
    Debug.Log("CollisionEnter");
}
```

Look here: [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)